# Unable to perform reordering of sign-up attributes in Azure B2C sign up page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to rearrange the order of Html Elements which is generated by Azure B2C Sign up page built in attributes. 
Like order 
Display Name
Family Name
City
State
Country

Please help me by providing the way of rearranging with tab order for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the field order by:

1. Editing the built-in policy
2. Selecting **Page UI customization**
3. Selecting **Local account sign-up page**
4. Moving the **Sign-up attributes** list items up and down using the drag icon to left of the attribute name.

Comment: Excellent!, @Koushikmondal, can you please mark this as the correct answer so others can refer to it?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "Editing the built-in policy"? I don't see anywhere I can select *Page UI customization* in my B2C tenant

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I've the same issue, I want my controls render in the following order: 1. Given Name 
2. Email 3. Password. But after reorder email and Given Name, when I save the change it is not getting reflected. Also there is no option to choose the order of password box.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the first answer, if anyone else stumbles across this issue:

1. Go to your Azure AD B2C
2. Select **User Flows (policies)**
3. Select the policy you wish to edit
4. Select **Page layouts**
5. Select the layout you wish to edit (mine was called **Local account sign up page**
6. Edit and re-order the fields as needed